# PDF to HTML/Image

Tags: php

i want to display the pdf files to the users in my site, with the condition that the users must not be able to download the original pdfs.

Hence i want to convert my pdfs into either an image or html and display them.

1) For this, what can be the best possible solution in php?

2) Do i need to convert the pdfs at the time of uploading them itself, or is it fine to convert them while displaying to the user ?

3) And also, is the conversion possible all at once, or page by page?

Please suggest.  (FYI, iam using Windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=134543

Quick google...

Comment: Fine, how can the conversion be made? Dynamically while displaying to the user, or while uploading them to the site? Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd want to do it on upload, then the user has no chance of intercepting your script and downloading your PDF...i'm not sure on the actual code, but the link looks good

Comment: Thanks for the link, i came to know that we can use imagemagick to convert pdf files to images. And i could try it successfully in my local system using command line... but iam not lucky with the imagick extension for using in my script.